# Is this code correct example of thread safe Singleton design pattern?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

Is below code correct example of thread safe Singleton pattern in Java ?

```
    class Singleton {
    private static Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Since static members are initialised, only once, at the time of class loading by JVM which is guaranteed to be thread safe, so does this not make above code example of thread safe Singleton class(Early loading) ?

Is there anything wrong with above statement ? If yes, then what minimum changes are required to convert it to thread safe Singleton class ?

Comment: it is perfectly thread safe.

Comment: You are correct in your statement regarding the initialisation of this class, however the instance is not final, and as such some unforeseen behaviour may occur when you assign another object to the variable.

Comment: please refer => http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html

Comment: you may also take a look to => http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-create-thread-safe-singleton-in-java-example.html

Comment: Thanks Vikrant. first link refers only to lazy initialisation examples where as 2nd link has mentioned the exact thing

Comment: The simplest solution is `enum Singleton { INSTANCE }` It's thread safe, lazy initialising and less error prone e.g. you can't create a `new Singleton()` or `new Singleton() { }` sub class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is guaranteed to be safe by the JLS. See [the holder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom): "since the class initialization phase is guaranteed by the JLS to be sequential, i.e., non-concurrent, no further synchronization is required in the static getInstance method during loading and initialization."

The holder pattern is more complex than what you want, but the important part is that `static final Something INSTANCE = new Something()` is safe no matter which class it is declared in. The benefit of the holder pattern compared to what you have is that the singleton won't be initialized until the first time it is used. This is helpful if you want to access other static members in your `Singleton` class when the cost of initializing the `Singleton` instance is expensive.

As [Lewis_McReu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746266/is-this-code-correct-example-of-thread-safe-singleton-design-pattern/48746328#comment84492379_48746266) and [user6690200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746266/is-this-code-correct-example-of-thread-safe-singleton-design-pattern/48746328#comment84492546_48746328) pointed out, you should declare the `INSTANCE` field `final` in order to ensure that you don't accidentally assign a different `Singleton` instance to the variable. You should also declare a private no-argument `Singleton()` constructor to prevent other instances from being created. To make it even more bulletproof, you should declare the `Singleton` class `final` so that you can't subclass it with a `public` constructor.

Comment: you refer to Initialization-on-demand holder idiom in your link. It is not lazy in the OP code.

Comment: The important part is that `static final Something INSTANCE = new Something()` is safe, no matter what class it is declared in.

Comment: Even if it is not `final`, it is thread-safe as far as initialization is concerned. It is dangerous in other ways however.

Comment: So not declaring the member variable final will prevent it from being thread safe Singleton ? Is final necessary ?

Comment: All singleton references should be declared `final` since by definition there should only be one instance ever created, so it makes no sense to reserve the ability to reassign the reference (unless you want to conditionally `null` it out at some future point in time).

Comment: To answer your question, it won't change the behavior of the code you posted. However, marking the field `final` will prevent you from accidentally writing something like `void setInstance(Singleton o) { INSTANCE = o; }`, which can be thread-unsafe, and is also very wrong for other reasons.

Comment: I could say even if it is `final`, it is not thread-safe as far as modification is concerned if this class is not immutable.